# Stedy space matrix numerically solution

Tags: matlab

The system is nonlinear with Eq of:

```
xdot = A(x) + B(x) u
```

where `x = [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8]T`  are system states (vectors) and A(x) nonlinear system matrix and B(x) is input matrix and u  is input signals.
]T mean transpose of matrix.

I have a matrix as :

```
S = [a11[(x7˙ − x7˙d ) + λ7 (x7 − x7d )]
    +a12[(x4˙ − x4˙d ) + λ4 (x4 − x4d )];
     a21[(x2˙ − x2˙d ) + λ2 (x2 − x2d )]
    +a22[(x5˙ − x5˙d ) + λ5 (x5 − x5d )];
     a31[(x3˙ − x3˙d ) + λ3 (x3 − x3d )]
    +a32[(x6˙ − x6˙d ) + λ6 (x6 − x6d )]]

x7dot  = x4 + x5sin(x7)tan(x9) + x6cos(x5)tan(x9)
x7ddot = x3 + x5sin(x6)tan(x2) + x3cos(x5)tan(x5)

x4dot  = x7 + x5sin(x7)tan(x2) + x3cos(x7)tan(x5)
x4ddot = x3 + x7sin(x2)tan(x2) + x2cos(x6)tan(x7)
```

,and so on.

where `x7˙  =` Is the derivative of Seventh state (vector x7).
      `x7˙d =` Is the derivative of desire  Seventh state  (vector xd7).

The question :How can we calculate`(∂ S/∂ x)` derivative of S matrix relation to xi;
As I read in an article this matrix doesn't have analytical solution and should be solve numerically.Which matlab's command can do this?

Comment: What's a "vector matrix"? In other words, what's the `size` of `A` and `B`? Mostly curiousity... And does formula (3) contain a conjugate transpose, or a derivative? Still, I'm not sure I'd be able to figure out your problem (the mathematical part) in a reasonable amount of time. For instance, I can only suspect that your variable for most of the derivatives is something like `t`, and `x` is another variable, which would also depend on `t`...

Comment: As I explained above size A(x) , B(x) depend on the size of the states derivatives and input control signal (u)